# How to remove some words from url?

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I remove '~' and '@abc.example.com' from url?

origin url: [https://example.com/~username@abc.example.com/](https://example.com/%7Eusername@abc.example.com/)
expect to display: https://example.com/user/

I already tried as in the apache conf:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /      
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/@abc.example.com(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/~(.*)$
    RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=301,L]

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
        Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
        Require method GET POST OPTIONS
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

But it isn't working and the 'username' is dynamic.